# How to tune number of epochs with skorch?

Tags: skorch

May I ask how I can find best number of epochs (not max_epochs) through cross validation when using skorch?

Is it possible to do something like:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_validate
from skorch import NeuralNetClassifier

net = NeuralNetClassifier(...)
params = {
    'n_epochs': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
}
gs = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=net,
    param_grid=params,
    refit=True,
    cv=inner_cv,
    scoring='accuracy',
)
test_predictions = cross_validate(
    gs,
    X,
    y,
    cv=outer_cv,
    scoring=scoring,
    verbose=0,
    n_jobs=n_cores_cv
)
...
```

If it is possible, may I ask how the models are evaluated on each n_epochs? Is an individual model fitted for each n_epochs, or the valid metrics are calculated and recorded along the training epochs of a single model, so that the model will be fitted only once for one split of dataset?